# how to match data in two excel and export to a new one

Tags: r, excel, match

I have two lists of stocks information in two different excel, one with 7 columns (`ID, Names, MarketCap...`) and the other 2 ("No." and "Names") I want to pick the information for every companies in the first excel but not in the second one, and export into a new excel. The searching criteria is the name of the company.

```
cdata$cqaId<-as.vector(cID[match(as.vector(c$Names),as.vector(cID[,1])),2])
#match the Names column in the first excel with the second one

miss<- cdata[which(is.na(cdata$cQaId)),]
#pick those that are not match

if (nrow(miss) > 0) {
    write.table(
        miss, 
        paste("U:\\groups\\stocksel\\production\\model\\customer\\customerList\\missing_",
        date.name.noDay, ".csv", sep=""), sep=",",col.names=T, row.names=F)
} 
#export into a new one
```

The problem now is

```
cdata$cqaId<-as.vector(cID[match(as.vector(c$Names),as.vector(cID[,1])),2])
```

this picking method only picks those with exact match. I want to also pick those pairs like "coca-cola" & "coca-cola. co". I'm thinking about writing sth to pick the companies from the second excel as long as the name contains the whole name that is in the first excel.

Comment: What language are you using? This seems a bit like Ruby.

Comment: I'm using R rather than Ruby

Comment: Hi slowlearner, thanks for the suggestion. But my reputation is too low to upload picture. Could you give me your email so I could send you the example pic? Thanks

Comment: Hi slowlearner, thank you for the suggestion. I will just type in the data as following since they are not large:

Comment: > dput(head(iris,4))
structure(list(conm = c(ALICO INC, ALICO INC, ALICO INC, BEAM INC), gvkey = c(1266, 
1266, 1266, 1408), datadate = c(9/1, 9/1, 9/1, 12/1), cid = c(9, 
10, 11, 10), cnms = c(CITROSUCO NORTH AMERICA, INC., LOUIS DREYFUS, CUTRALE CITRUS JUICE, THE EDRINGTON GROUP), class = "data.frame")

Comment: That `structure` is invalid, it causes a `Error: unexpected symbol` error. You're missing something. Don't type the output of `dput` into a comment, please hit the edit button on your question then copy and paste the output (i.e. the `structure`) into your question, then save the question. And besides which, the variables in your code don't seem to match the variables in the data...